# Problem with charset when inserting text into a MySQL DataBase with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm trying to insert text into a MySQL DataBase from a form using PHP.
Problem is, when I check the DataBase in phpmyadmin, I find that special characters like ü, ö, ä, è, é, à... are being corrupted, and I get things like `Ã¼Ã¶Ã¤Ã©Ã¨Ã`.I've tried the following:

- Putting `accept-charset="latin1_swedish_ci"` in the `<form>` tag
- Setting `default_charset = "latin1_swedish_ci"` in the php.ini file
- Putting `mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'latin1_swedish_ci');` and `mysql_query('SET NAMES latin1_swedish_ci');` after the `mysqli_connect()` function
- Setting the collation of the DataBase, the table and the individual columns to `latin1_swedish_ci`

I noticed that running the query directly in the phpmyadmin the values weren't corrupted, so I suppose the error must be somewere in the PHP and/or the MySQL connection.
Also, I tried doing the same with `utf-8_general_ci`, and obtained same results.
It seems to be ignoring anything I do.
Advice and ideas welcome. Thanks guys,
Sean

Comment: What is the character encoding of the page containing the form ?

Comment: `accept-charset="latin1_swedish_ci"` is no valid HTML. Please use a fitting charset, see [HTML docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset). You might be looking for `latin1`, [list of all registered charsets](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets).

Comment: And your question looks like that you don't know how MySQL handles charsets, so [read about that here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html).

Comment: There is a confusion on the scenario stated above. First part of above you said - I check the DataBase in phpmyadmin, I find that special characters like ü, ö, ä, è, é, à... are being corrupted, and I get things like Ã¼Ã¶Ã¤Ã©Ã¨Ã AND then you said - I noticed that running the query directly in the phpmyadmin the values weren't corrupted. Please make sure are you found data corrupted in PHPMYADMIN?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.                                          Well, the corruption only happens when I try to insert records using my PHP script, not when I run the query directly in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not properly say if that is the cause of your problem, but in any case you can not put a Mysql specifier of charset and collation neither into the HTML form nor into PHP.ini.

Right now you use the MySQL value somewhat blindly and put it everywhere you assume it fit - without even knowing. Don't do that. First of all decide which encoding you want to use and accept. From your question I would say that is **latin1**.

So configure HTML and PHP appropriately:

```
<form accept-charset="latin1">
```

For the HTML form element. Note that there is no `latin1_swedish_ci` in HTML, see the [HTML docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset).

A next and similar point is in your php.ini setting. There doesn't exists something like you put there. Change it to **latin1** as well:

```
default_charset = "latin1"
```

With these two settings corrected, the browser is aware what the encoding of the page is that contains the form, and the form even signals the browser the accepted encoding of the data passed back to the server.

So this should ensure that the data you have inside the PHP variables is **latin1** encoded. You can then pass this data into your database if you properly configured the encoding of the database client, the database server, the encoding of the connection between the two and naturally the encoding of the data in the database as well.

However, the proper setup of the form is the very first step you need to do before you can ensure that the mysql connection isn't wrangling stuff up.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply! Much appreciated. Thanks to your advice I managed to fix the problem, since I did not set the PHP variables as 'latin1' but as 'latin1_swedish_ci', which as you point out is incorrect in HTML and won't work in the php.ini file.   Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you tried this or not... but I had kind of the same problem while inserting Hebrew into a MySQL database.
I did the following:
Database tables are collation is: utf8_unicode_ci

In PHP I do this:

```
@ $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$db->set_charset('utf8');
```

I create a new connection and than I specify  the connetion as UTF-8.

This solved my problem when dealing with Hebrew...

Comment: OP is looking for latin1 encoding, not UTF-8.

Comment: I do it like this:                                               $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
 
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'latin1_swedish_ci');
mysql_query('SET NAMES latin1_swedish_ci');

Comment: Well.... I did it with UTF-8 it doesn't mean that the exact same thing can't be done with latin1_swedish_ci - Next time I will make sure to include the exact encoding asked for in the question.

Comment: The way your doing it, it should be: ` mysql_set_charset('latin1_swedish_ci', $dbc); `

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the collation and the MYSQL connection collation are both latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: I don't think collation would have anything to do with it.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was solved by changing the collation of the database, don't know, maybe I was lucky :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set character enconding of the page to:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For those Hebrew users:

**HTML PAGE:**

```
<html lang="he">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

**PHP FORM**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$con = mysqli_connect("HOST","DB_USER","PASSWORD","DB_NAME");
$con->set_charset('utf8');
```

**DB, TABLE, FEILDs COLLATION**

`utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score -1):

You may user

```
mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
```

before executing MySQL query